# Creating a PopulateController to handle populating of DropDownLists that are in PartialViews & EditorTemplates

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am fairly new to ASP.NET MVC5 and I am building my first web application. I noticed that some DropDownLists will be used all throughout the application so decided to create EditorTemplates for them. For example, States, Countries, etc.. The views that need them use the @Html.EditorFor helper to insert them into the page.

My main concern is how to populate these globally with methods that return Json such as GetStates(), GetCountries(). At first I was thinking that I would have to create a method in each controller that renders a view that it is used on. Then I said why don't I just create a controller that has all of my populate methods that are not going to change throughout the site such as GlobalController, PopulateController, AjaxController, etc..

Is this a normal thing to do or is there a specific naming convention for a controller? I have never seen an examples before so I am wondering if there is a better way to handle these things.

Answer (score 1):

I think the naming is a preference. I broke out most of my read only Type tables in a database into a `TypeController`. It is easy to find whenever I need to Add or modify a Type table.

Personally, I place any table/entity that supports crud operations into its own controller. You end up with a lot of controllers but it makes maintenance less of a hassle.

If you are going to be updating combos with your controller then you will probably be returning json via the `return Json(myModel,JsonBehaviour.AllowGet);` unless you are using extension functions for custom ui framework.

I have always used the repository pattern for data entities and have found the single best time saver in mvc to be the use of a mapping library such as AutoMapper to map from Mvc Models to Domain objects and vice-sersa.

Comment: Thanks for the great response! I use AutoMapper to map from my DataLayer(EF6 DbFirst AutoGenerated layer) to my ModelLayer(Pocos/Dtos). One thing I am confused about is when using stored procedures they return a complex object such as Customer_GetList_Result so I have to map this to my model and I lost foreign key object properties such as Customer.Category, Customer.Address since they are not in my complex type. How does one handle this?

Comment: I have come across similar issues, however, I am still using Linq2Sql so I don't get a lot of the plumbing code in EF that handles entity relationships. The vast majority of my models are one to one with the DO, or at least can be filled by a sp that contains a subset of fields that are mapped correctly. I have created custom Edit View Models to contain additional properties and they have to be manually populated. I try to avoid that as much as possible.